# Set checkboxs are checked using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to set checkboxs are checked using jquery.My jquery code and html code are given below.

```
<script>

      $(".two"+res1).prop("checked", true);
</script>

<input name="" type="checkbox" value=""  class="two<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
```

Any body help me?

Comment: is `$(".two"+res1).prop("checked", true);` in a dom ready handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery code should be in ready state.. And your code is correct, hope you already loop the code.

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".two"+res1).prop("checked", true);
});
</script>
```

or you can use like this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $(".two"+res1).attr("checked",true);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".two"+res1).prop("checked", true); is a document ready function so you can do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(".two"+res1).prop("checked", true);  
    });      
</script>
```